# In which countries is that “long time no see” greeting common?

Tags: idioms, singapore-english

I used to hear this greeting several times a day when in Singapore.

In other English-speaking countries, is this idiomatic expression known, do people consider it funny, or just a terrible misconception of English?

Comment: Related: [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Long time no see" is used in the UK.

It is informal. I do not know how widespread its use is but I expect people of most UK social groups and of most UK regions would recognise and understand it even if it was not a form of greeting they would use themselves.

Comment: Yes, but is it used commonly, and is it very informal?

Comment: Also in the U.S., although we split it with a comma. :)

Comment: @Benoit - I have edited my answer to address your supplemental questions. It is a phrase I would use without much hesitation in speech in informal settings. I don't recall having used it as a greeting in writing (as normally I can't "see" the other party when writing to them).

Comment: I don't think I hear it as often in the Midwestern US as I used to.  It seems to have been cliched to the point that people are starting to avoid using it as a common greeting.  It's still used as a trope, as @The Raven mentions in another answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's common in Japanese (*ohisashiburi da ne*). Standard in US English. Most likely a feature in most languages.

In English it's also a trope, so that you can play off "long time, no **_** " in a variety of other contexts.

Answer (score 5):

It is common and informal in AmE. It is idiomatic (i.e. pedantically agrammatic but common enough not to sound 'off').

I have heard that it is a direct loan-translation of Mandarin 'hao jiu bu jian'.

Answer (score 1):

In common use in Ireland as well.

As for etymology, I'll put forward that is has a comma and comes from USA and specifically from Western films, where you'd oft here an american indian would say "long time, no see".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with n0nChun that it is very common in India. The reason could be that most of the Indian languages have an equivalent that would roughly translate to *long time no see*

Answer (score -1):

Um, I'm Indian, and most of the guys of my generation here, have caught up to it!