# Is "unmissable" a valid word?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, negation, is-it-a-word, affixes

I noticed an advert on TV advertising "unmissable" shows coming up. MS Word marks it as a spelling mistake, but the Mac OS is OK with it.

I don't particularly like it.

Comment: It's in a [recognised dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unmissable). If you don't like it, don't use it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english)

Comment: Fair enough I guess.

Comment: Not all utterings in advertising can necessarily be found in dictionaries or be declared as valid 'words' officially. They can be used in appropriate context.

Comment: My Microsoft Outlook doesn't like it either - but Microsoft is not the arbiter of acceptable English words, nor does its spelling checker purport to be a dictionary.

Comment: I would use "not to be missed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to update your MS-Word. *Unmissable* is a word that can be found in most [dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1089&bih=520&q=english+dictionary&oq=english+dic&gs_l=img.3.0.0l10.651.1913.0.2833.11.11.0.0.0.0.234.878.8j2j1.11.0...0.0...1ac.1.5.img.ILl-Nx3-qWM). It is a pretty boring word but we can't deny the fact that it is used by some people.

Answer (score 3):

Words can be invented. If it uses a root that people are familiar with and affixes that are understandable then people will know what you are saying, although it might sound weird. Sounding unusual might be what they are striving for. I know what *unmissable* would mean and I could put it in a sentence of my own, so why not? If you don't like, then that is probably a good enough reason to avoid it.