# Is 'quantitate' a synonym for 'quantify' or just a misnomer?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, is-it-a-word

I have always used *quantify*, but have been encountering *quantitate* more and more in scientific literature. Is *quantitate* a "valid" verb and a synonym for *quantify*? Otherwise is there a subtle difference in the meaning of these two words?

I forgot to mention that in some dictionaries both words exist while in others, *quantitate* is not featured, e.g. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=quantitate

Comment: [quantitate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quantitate?q=quantitate). So, in a word, yes.

Comment: @MattЭллен I have checked oxford dictionaries, just as well as a couple of others. _quantitate_ is featured on some, and not on others.

Comment: I think you should read [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english) and its answer to get a better understanding of how language works.

Comment: @MattЭллен so what you are suggesting is that _quantitate_ is a word that is most likely in the process of establishing as a synonym to _quantify_, and that it doesn't matter whether or not it is right originally, as long as enough people adopt it into their language?

Comment: I would go further and say it *is* a word that is a synonym for *quantify* because enough people have used it that it has made it into the OED (and by extension Oxford Online Dictionaries).

Comment: @MattЭллен ok, I see your point. Do you mind post your argument as an answer?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1021/ac00251a712

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Valid word* is a difficult thing to quantify. As I've [said before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english), a word exists as long as people use it.

You say in your question that you have read it in literature, so therefore we must conclude that it does exist, and, given the context of its use, is a synonym for *quantify*.

The meaning according to OED<sup>1</sup> is a synonym for *quantify*, chiefly used in biological or medical contexts, so I feel quite sure that its use is typical.

[image: quantify vs quantitate ngram]

As can be seen in the above ngram, *quantify* is more popular than *quantitate*, but *quantitate*'s use is not insignificant in proportion.

The main difference between the two words is that *quantitate* is (i.e. can be) used to mean "to perform quantitative analysis upon", which is not really synonymous with *quantify*. Also, I think it's fair to say, outside of scientific literature, you are unlikely to encounter *quantitate*.

(1): "quantitate, v.". OED Online. March 2013. Oxford University Press. 20 May 2013 http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155922?redirectedFrom=quantitate.

Comment: Nice answer, and thanks for introducing me to ngrams using Google Books (was not familiar with it from before). I am a little reserved about "it is used therefore it's valid" idea, since it disregards the bad use of language in literature which happens... Otherwise thanks for a great answer

Comment: I don't mind the broad principle of "it is used therefore it's valid", but it needs some refinement to account for levels of intentionality in using new forms.  At the extreme, I think we can agree that 'hte' is not a valid synonym of 'the', despite widespread use and easy recognition of this form.

Comment: Can we agree that? OED has "of" as an auxiliary verb. I mean, I would correct hte to the, but still.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is one of the first uses of the noun quantitation by Arthur Ellis Esq in the Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Vol. 51, No. 3 (Sep., 1888), pp. 567-598:

I VENTURE to use this word " quantitation " as one which will be readily understood by the Statistical Society, if not by the outer world. It is among objects of the Society, while remaining unsatisfied with bald facts or conclusions, or classification is, to find out " how much " and to what extent facts are facts, or, in other words, to test the meaning of facts. "Quantitation," therefore, expresses in one word-which may be an ugly one but is never-the-less a useful word-what we aim at in an investigation before the notice of the Society. (There is the word " quantification," used by writers on logic, including Sir William Hamilton, applied to the predicate. I remember a student of logic calling this word an invention of the enemy for the confusion of the understanding. Precisely because it applies to logic and not to statistical facts, I am disinclined to use it, and it contains one more syllable which, although one more or less among so many may seem to be no matter, is a disadvantage.)

Answer (score 3):

Purnendu commented above that "quantitate" is one to two orders of magnitude more frequent than "quantify", yet no source was cited. A search of articles on the American Chemical Society's website revealed 9129 results for quantitate and 71388 results for quantify. This simple analysis certainly argues in the other direction. Interestingly, the top result in both searches is an article by David Kurtz in *Anal. Chem.* **1982**, *54* (14), 1456A, titled "To Quantify or to Quantitate", where the term "quantify" is encouraged by the author.

Answer (score 0):

In chemistry one differentiates between quantitative (how much?) and qualitative (what?) analysis.  These words have been in vogue since the 19th century.  There is no such phrase as quantifying or quantificative analysis.  In the Analytical chemistry literature the use of "quantitate" is at least an order of magnitude more frequent than "quantify" quite possibly two orders of magnitude.

Enough pontification!

Comment: Even pontiffs are requested to use the link widget to prevent woolly answers drowning EL&U..Without that your answers won't get the recognition they deserve. +1 as a welcome..

Answer (score -2):

How many people have to tell you that it's a BS made up word for it to be taken out of the dictionary?  Word evolution is certainly a thing, but this particular word isn't evolution.  It's bullsh*t, made up by people attempting to puff up their grant proposals by truncating and misusing a perfectly good word.  QUANTITATIVE data flows from the QUANTIFICATION of results...it's that simple.  This is the same as using the word ORIENTATE in lieu of ORIENT.  I promise, no one will think you are stupid if you use the proper word instead of its puffed up imaginary cousin.

Comment: Given that all words are imagined at some point, I'm not sure what argument you are making.