# Does the word "simpleness" actually exist?

Tags: etymology, nouns, is-it-a-word

I always thought the word "simpleness" didn't exist and this was even confirmed by some American friends of mine. However, I tried to look it up on some online dictionaries and I was surprised to find out that some of them report this word while others don't.
What's the story behind "simpleness"?

Comment: You don't want to use it instead of simplicity; that would sound uneducated or inarticulate.

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/simple?q=simpleness#simple__21

Comment: *Simpleness* is not quite the same thing as *simplicity*: Syn: *artlessness, greenness, guilelessness, ingenuousness, innocence, naiveness, naivety* (also *naïvety*) [chiefly British], *naturalness, simplemindedness, simpleness, simplicity, unsophistication, unworldliness, viridity* (http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/simpleness); freedom from difficulty or hardship or effort (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Simpleness)

Comment: see "[Is 'quantitate' a synonym for 'quantify' or just a misnomer?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114448/is-quantitate-a-synonym-for-quantify-or-just-a-misnomer)" for how to tell if something is a word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Simpleness* does not necessarily mean the same as *simplicity*.

For example, *simple time* in music is a time signature (basic rhythm) which is not *compound time*. Simple time has *simpleness*, not simplicity.

OED has a number of similar definitions:

> **simpleness** noun
>
> 1. Absence of pride, ostentation, or pretentiousness; plain or unassuming disposition or manners.
> 2. Absence of duplicity or guile; innocence, integrity, guilelessness.
> 3. a. Deficiency in knowledge or learning, ignorance; also, lack of mental acuteness, intellectual weakness, foolishness.
> 4. a. Poor or lowly condition; also, lack of elegance or refinement; plainness of dress, etc.
> 5. Absence of complexity; freedom from complications; simple character.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By saying that "does not necessarily mean the same" it's not clear if it could still be used as a synonim of "simplicity". Can you clarify?

Comment: This is a simple sentence. It is a model of simplicity. All of the examples in my answer have *simpleness* as the "quality of being simple," not simplicity. *Simpleness* is more of a technical term, perhaps.

Comment: You can find some good examples of how _simpleness_ is properly used in the [BYU copus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). There are 10 hits. I would suspect that most careful users would either restrict it to its technical meanings, as in music, or its suggestion that a person described as having the trait of simpleness is essentially _simpleminded_ or _intellectually challenged_, to put it into PC-speak. [Google Ngrams](http://rdd.me/beofv00e) shows very few examples of _simpleness_: here are [some examples](http://rdd.me/r5geksxl).

Comment: OTOH, probably 9 times out of 10 if you see "simpleness" the person meant "simplicity", but couldn't come up with that word for some reason (brain-fart, bad vocabulary, etc.).

Comment: @T.E.D. yeah indeed, especially when Italians try to translate something to english :-)