# Why are these words ungrammatical

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

I can't find the reason why : riceful and antful are ungrammatical. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in the site for [linguistics.se].

Comment: related: [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english)

Comment: 'Ungrammatical' in the sense usually used here means 'breaking some rule of syntax'. Since syntax doesn't apply to individual words or non-words, your question should be 'Why are _riceful_ and _antful_ not acceptable words?' Are you saying that any combinations of letters might properly be regarded as an acceptable word, that adding -ful to any noun should generate an acceptable word, or just that you would like 'antful' and 'riceful' to be acceptable words?

Comment: This may interest you: http://www.thefullwiki.org/-ful http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-ful and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ful

Answer (score 3):

I think you've misunderstood what *grammatical* means. The words you've cited are simply not used by anyone I've ever heard or read.

If they had a meaning they could be put in a sentence.

Let's give one a meaning: *antful* means the amount of something that could fill an ant.

> You've got thousands of antfuls of milk there.

I have used that word grammatically.

A word without context is not ungrammatical, it's just meaningless.

Comment: [Here's a 1927 instance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22another+riceful%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (from someone with obviously limited competence in English) of *riceful* apparently being used to mean *bowlful of rice*. A similar underlying neologistic principle also applies in an 1893 reference to a [*wineful, meatful, smokeful state of bliss*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wineful%2C+meatful%2C+smokeful+state+of+bliss%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but that one never caught on either.