# How do I find Oxford/Merriam Words by Year?

Tags: dictionaries

Is there a way to search for when a word become a recognized word? My guess is that words that have been around "forever" were part of early unabridged English dictionaries. For modern history though, how can we see when a word became recognized, perhaps by a dictionary?

What would be ideal is to see something like this by year.  For example, we know Oxford added *bromance* at some point. What year?

Comment: What do you mean by an official word and when a word becomes official? I am unaware that there's an officiating committee judging words. Edit: a word is not official because or when it's added to a dictionary. Dictionaries are years behind usage.

Comment: You mean like this: http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/previous-updates/june-2015-update/new-words-list-june-2015/

Comment: @AlanCarmack, maybe you're confused. I've updated my question with an example.

Comment: @Catija, precisely. It'd be nice to be able to search by year or see when a given word was actually added.

Comment: I edited my first comment. Words don't become official because or when they're added to a dictionary.

Comment: Search on the OED blog: [Bromance](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/03/brother-buddy-bro/) got inducted in the holy halls of Oxford in 2013.

Comment: @Helmar, that does answer the example, yes. I'm looking for a search tool of some kind for any new word, frenemy, hella, etc.

Comment: Just google "frenemy added to dictionary"; first entry after ODO & MW gives the answer. 2009. So maybe your desired search tool is google. ;) For hella it's even the first result.

Comment: Almost @Helmar. Now I want to see all the words added in 2009 for example.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, Good to know.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote how to do research on the English language at English.StackExchange.com? Lol.

Comment: Well then go back to the link @Catija provided and go to back to [previous updates](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/previous-updates/).

Comment: If you really want to know this, it should be extremely easy to set up a spreadsheet with each year as listed on the link I posted earlier and then sort the list alphabetically or by year depending on what you want to see.

Comment: @Helmar, I can't say it's not what I asked for. Leaves a little to be desired, but... Okay.

Comment: @Catija, Well sure I could do that. It's OED, and it's back to 2000. What words were added in 1964? What words were added in 1944, 1834? I mean, this is helpful, but um, it looks like to really get this type of information I'm going to have to go away from dictionaries altogether.  Use Google Trends perhaps. I prefer using dictionaries because that gives the word more legitimacy in it's usage. I don't want to see the first year 'robot' was used. I want to know when it was _part_ _of_ _the_ _language_, ubiquitous, etc.

Comment: @john Before the internet became ubiquitous, the only way to add something to a dictionary would be writing a new one. Between the first and second editions of the complete O.E.D., released in 1933 and 1989, there were [four supplemental volumes](http://public.oed.com/history-of-the-oed/oed-editions/) to the first edition which should include all but 5,000 words added between the editions. Granted, those were released in alphabetical rather than chronological order but I think it's the closest thing to an update list available, unless you're willing to skim through collegiate dictionaries.

Comment: @Tonepoet, that's very interesting. That definitely changes my view on how to approach dictionaries. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it assumes that there is such a thing as an "official" word in English.

Comment: @Chenmunka, maybe you can suggest an edit instead. The idea is to get the year a word became prominent or commonly used. Official in this case is a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: You should edit your question to remove all mentions of "official".

Comment: @tchrist, done. Perhaps we can have a conversation now about who at least has some authority on being consulted. The question is about chronology more than anything. But if the discussion has to be about dictionaries first, then great.

Comment: Thanks. This way people who just read the question won't be distracted discussion of "official" words.

Comment: Do you want to know when a dictionary company decided to add a word/which edition it first appeared in? Or do you want to know, irrespective of dictionary, when a word first appeared in the wild (for a verifiable usage)? The first is interesting for history of dictionaries, the latter more for linguistics. OED does the latter; for whatever entry of a word it has, it also has a quote of the earliest known sentence where that word has been reported.

Comment: @Mitch, linguistics. I want to know when real people decided that using the word made sense. So, literary usage. That makes total sense.

Comment: @John,  I would suggest removing all reference to "official" and ask for how to find the date of inclusion of words.

Comment: @John To answer the question I think you are answering, for a given word when did it first appear, there are two current easy methods: 1) for a curated version, look in the OED (if you have a public library card in the US or UK, you probably have access to it online through that library); every word has a citation for its first occurrence in print. 2) [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) gives a frequency timeline up until about 2000. 'Bromance' doesn't appear because it is much more recent; 'metrosexual' seems to have started in the early 90's.

Comment: @John But if your question is, your title question, literally to find for a given year what are the new words for that year, then that is more difficult with online tools. I think it maybe be possible to search OED for a year and it will return all the words with a mention of that date, but it is not restricted to first quotations (it might be later quotations). Presumably someone at OED or NGrams can access their database with a query for a specific element like 'year of first occurrence' but that is not available to the front end that we have access to.

Comment: @Mitch, yeah. So, if I can, cut right to it; what is the value of this question (in its current form)? I'm not sure. Can I open a book or website and say, more or less, this is the year that any one word rose beyond some quantified level of obscurity. The collegiate OED's seem to be pretty good and NGrams substantially more so. So, does this (or another) question answer, 'How to find the year/moment/time a given word came into the common English language'. Secondly, is that of value? I think it definitely is, but are both answered in the affirmative?

Comment: This has been immensely helpful to me, so thank you for your input Mitch. If my summary of the issue(s) is not accurate, then please let me know where this discussion/question might be headed, presumably to be of more value to ELU.

Comment: There are lots of issues, all worth discussing and elaborating at length. In short, the great majority of words don't just pop into the world spontaneously - people's accents change over time and so the pronunciation of a word for the same concept, or people start using a word metaphorically and it slips over to mean something distinct. When those things happen is a collective effort rather than the creative imagination of one person at one time writing a notarized document. The OED depends on independent researchers submitting a purported instance with date; NGrams has metadata date problems

Comment: @Mitch, so, I pretty much have my answer, but going over this in more detail with the additional considerations you've raised would be interesting. Should I revise this question to the tune of "How are words created and how has the history of the language quantified their births and/or deaths", etc.? Extremely broad I know, but I'm still looking for what needs to be done. I can take the time to put such a question together, but is it worth it, or should the current question be closed, revised in light of that, etc. Thanks.

Comment: I thought this was closable, but it's worth an extended answer. Let me write something up.

Comment: The overarching topic here (wordness) has been approached before on ELU. But there is no single 'authority' that everyone would agree has the authority to pronounce on whether a given candidate word is an actual English word. Inclusion in the OED (without an 'obsolete' tag) is often taken as sufficient evidence of wordness, but there are estimated to be hundreds of thousands of English words not defined in OED. Some people claim that certain affixes are almost universally productive, but this is a minority opinion. English is annoyingly/gloriously idiosyncratic.

Comment: 'Why would anyone downvote _how to do research on the English language_ at English.StackExchange.com (sic)?' Because requests for resources have been specifically off topic for years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you find Oxford/Merriam words by year? It's not terribly complicated but we should look at what all those things mean and imply first.

What is a word? I'm not going to try to explain that exactly except to explain what is around it. Speech came before writing, and writing is an attempt at recording a throat/mouth modulated sound stream into what we think is being said. distinct parts of that sound stream are cognitively separable into what are generally known as 'words'.

Language, which existed long before writing, didn't pop out of thin air; from subtle variations in air passage grunts, it slowly accreted features, to become the information portal we have today. The actual process of language evolution is a difficult study. Nobody was there at the beginning to say 'Aha! Those grunts are now a language'. We can attempt that now with animals and there is lots of language like abilities. But it is not a sharp process where one day you don't have it and the next day you do.

Individual words, which existed long before dictionaries and writing, didn't pop out of thin air; they slowly gained currency being modified little by little by sound changes, by semantic drift, by invading overlords and other-speaking childcare, by commonly made mistakes. 'Ward', for caretaker, is from Old English/Germanic; the Norman invaders speaking Old French had previously gotten what eventually became 'guard' from a different earlier German invasion and had already had a sound change from 'w-' to 'gu-'. The sound change happened slowly in northern Old French; the borrowing of the word 'guard' a little faster but still not immediate.

Dictionaries, which existed long before Sam Johnson and/or English, are created as one kind of book making process, with lots of data gathering and structuring that need to be cross-referenced and edited for quality and consistency. Coming up with a word list for a language has been around since the ancients, to help with learning or translation. Dictionaries with explanations or definitions evolved from that. With printing, they became even more elaborate, with grammar or examples.

A handful of words are neologisms, new words that did, contrary to all I've been saying so far, pop out of thin air. Created by a journalist for humor, an engineer creating a new machine, a doctor who finds something they've never seen before. The neologizer stays up late at night and in a burst of inspiration, the word flashes across their eyes, they type it up, it's printed the next day (in the days of yore writers had to have their words 'printed' with 'ink' on 'paper').

But a dictionary is a technical work with human authors (usually in the plural because it is so labor intensive). Some dictionaries are written for school children, others are written for foreign language learners, some are even meant to be an ongoing attempt at recording the state of the language.

Even if there is in fact an exact timestamp of when a part of an utterance becomes this magical thing called a word, there is still the difficulty of *others* pin-pointing exactly when this may have occurred. Records aren't perfect. A printed work isn't universally known to the world. Even computer information isn't universally known to the world instantaneously. So it takes lots of readers to come up with earlier and earlier citations to get a more and more accurate date of first appearance.

When a large collection of writing (called a corpus) is digitized, it then becomes easier to apply computer methods to word analysis. But there may still be difficulties: if using optical character recognition, letters in strange older fonts may be mischaracterized (literally!) and dates for documents may be chosen inappropriately.

This is all a long explanation to say that currently, in English, the best resources for what you want are:

- the Oxford English Dictionary - they give citations for the earliest known evidence of a word, and they update their database continuously. They've moved off a print model to computer model (they print from their database now). For any particular word, there may be lots of evidence that shows that a particular neologism was printed in a certain publication, but often neologisms just aren't that new and someone else thought of it first, so there's always doubt. 
  You can search the dictionary for words and then look at the entries to see which meaning you want. And then there'll be a number of citations starting with the earliest one found so far.
- Google NGrams - they have a huge corpus of digitized library books. With computer techniques you can search for words, and they return a graph of the frequency of the word for each year since, up to 2000. if the line is 0 up to a certain data and then shoots up afterwards, then you have good evidence (not incontrovertible) that that is when the word was invented.

Comment: Isn't this answering the question at [What are the criteria {for the adoption of} new words into English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To answer the question 'How to find out _when_..?' I felt like a lot of explanation was necessary. If it also answers 'what are the criteria...?' along the way, then so much the better. I actually don't think it does the latter that well. All I do is show, well actually only claim, that 'wordness' is vague whatever the criteria are.

Comment: This is good stuff Mitch. My favorite part is "writers had to have their words 'printed' with 'ink' on 'paper'", but my second favorite part is OED and NGrams. Thanks a bunch, +more if I could.

Comment: 'How to find out when (Oxford/Merriam Words first include)' is a request for resources / resource access and thus off-topic.